# Perl variables becoming empty in if statement

Tags: perl, variables, if-statement

This is driving me crazy, Perl is simply losing the value of a variable once I enter an if statement... and the weird this is, its only that variable, any other variable will not lose its value

```
open (MYFILE, "b");

my $haysack = "";
while (<MYFILE>)
{
    $haysack  = $haysack . "$_";
}
close (MYFILE);

open (MYFILE2, "ip_range");
my $needles = "";
while (<MYFILE2>)
{
    $needles  = $needles . "$_";
}
close (MYFILE2);

my $someOtherValue = "blabla";

while ($needles =~ m/(.*?)\n/g)
{
    $needle = $1;

    if ($haysack =~ m/$needle/ims)
    {
        print "FOUND :  $needle\n";
        print "$someOtherValue\n";
    }
}
```

So the code succesfully enters the if statement, but once it does I get the following output:

```
FOUND: 
blabla
```

can anyone help?

Comment: If you put a "print '$needle\n'" statement before the if statement, what happens?

Comment: You might want to have a look at File::Slurp for the reading part.

Comment: This is exactly where the perl debugger comes in handy. Run `perl -d myscript.pl` and step through the code using `n`. Print the value of `$needle` using `p $needle` once you get inside the while loop. Also, it would be helpful if you gave a small sample of the contents of your files.

Comment: If you have a blank line in your input, it would explain this behaviour. The error comes of a flawed approach. Why bother reading the whole file into the needle variable if you are going to split it into lines anyway? Also, this sounds like it could be solved with grep.

Comment: There are [better ways](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-an-entire-file-all-at-once%3f) of putting the contents of a file in a variable.  Also, a needle is customarily sought in a *haystack*, not a *haysack* [sic].

Answer (score 1):

This really should be a comment, since it's not an answer, but comments don't allow code formatting, so:

Can you provide a complete, runnable, self-contained, *minimal* example which demonstrates the problem without extraneous moving parts, such as reading files?  Something similar to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $haysack = "Foo
Bar
Baz
";

my $needles = "a
b
c
";

while ($needles =~ m/(.*?)\n/g) {
    my $needle = $1;

    if ($haysack =~ m/$needle/ims) {
        print "FOUND :  $needle\n";
    }
}
```

...except that mine runs perfectly, producing the output

```
FOUND :  a
FOUND :  b
```

rather than failing.  Note that, in the process of creating a minimal failing example, you are very likely to discover the solution to your problem...

As far as general troubleshooting advice, `use strict` and `use warnings` if you aren't already doing so.  Check the value of `$1` after doing the outer match to verify that `$needle` will be getting the value you expect it to.

Comment: Problem was solved, the issue was once again bad encoding in one of the files which caused no match except for empty characters thank you everyone